# Amcharts are not displying in tablet/ipad?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, amcharts

I am using java script am-charts for displaying charts for tablet application.
There is one problem which i am facing during development

- whenever i am opening same links in two tabs, charts are not display
  in both tabs.
- Whenever i am opening different link in application, charts are not display

> `<a  href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_BLANK">Facebook</a>`

Can you please guide me, how could i solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call chart.validateNow() after you show your list item.

Comment: I was using
document.getElementById('bardiv').style.display='inline';
Now I am using
document.getElementById('bardiv').style.display='block';

It works thanks for your support